# How to add title in button from array in swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, uibutton

I have an Array and I'd like to know how can I add title to 4 UIButtons using `sender.tag` in Swift 4

This is my array:

```
let answer: array = ["Black","Green","Red","Gray"]
```

Comment: `array` it is not a Swift type. Btw Swift is a type inferred language `let answer = ["Black","Green","Red","Gray"]`

Comment: `sender` is available when the button is touched.  Are you wanting to set the titles when the buttons are pressed?  What are the 4 tag values? `0` through `3`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `sender.tag` as an index into the `answer` array.  Use `guard` to make sure `sender.tag` is a valid index (so it doesn't crash):

```
let answer = ["Black", "Green", "Red", "Gray"]

@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard answer.indices.contains(sender.tag) else { return }

    sender.setTitle(answer[sender.tag], for: .normal)
}
```

If you hook your buttons up to this `@IBAction` and make your `tag` values `0` through `3`, then the titles will get set when get set when the buttons are pressed.

---

If your buttons are part of an outlet collection:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

you can set them like this (in `viewDidLoad()`, for example):

```
buttons.forEach { $0.setTitle(answer[$0.tag], for: .normal)
```

Again, be sure to set your `tag` values in the range `answer.indices`.

Answer (score 0):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let array = ["Black","Green","Red","Gray"]

    var oldButton = UIButton()

    for i in 1...array.count {

        let button = UIButton()

        if i == 1 {

            button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 40, width: 90, height: 20)
            button.tag = i
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.selctorButton(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
            button.setTitle(array[button.tag - 1], for: .normal)

        }

        else {

            button.frame = CGRect(x: oldButton.frame.maxX + 10, y: 40, width: 90, height: 20)
            button.tag = i
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.selctorButton(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
            button.setTitle(array[button.tag - 1], for: .normal)

        }

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        view.addSubview(button)
        oldButton = button

    }
}

@objc func selctorButton(_ sender : UIButton){

    print(sender.tag)

}
```

}